# How to change the background color of certain text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue in JavaScript I need to change the back ground color of the text.
I am printing an coupon in JavaScript it works fine I am using an white paper to print

ex:Format how the output recipt will look

```
***********************
Shopping  center

amount :3450

Foodworld one store
India
************************
```

now I need to change background color of the text Foodworld to one store to Red and  text  color  to  black. How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Just put Foodworld one store in a div and give any id like this (divid) to that div and call this function.

Use this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_color()
{
    document.getElementById("divid").style.color='black';
    document.getElementById("divid").style.backgroundColor='red';
}
</script>
```